# HTML Template variable set in PHP found "mystically" reassigned when template builds page

Tags: php, arrays, templates

PROBLEM
The template variable set in PHP is being changed before the template can use the value that was set.

OVERVIEW
The template variable is set to 1 by PHP, then when the template variable is used in an if statement
 the template variable has been set to 0 by some unknown method.  How can this happen ?

The assignment happens within a foreach loop in the middle of the php script:

```
$xyz = 1;
$template->assign_vars(array(
    'B_XYZ' => $xyz,
    ));
```

Template code snippet is:

```
{B_XYZ}  <<<< Reports value = 0 on webpage: Is supposed to be =1
<!-- IF B_XYZ -->
code
<!—ENDIF 
```

There is another set of template variable assignments at the end of the file
The template variable B_XYZ is not used again in this last set of assignments.

```
$template->assign_vars(array(
x => 'hello',
many entries,
    )); 

include 'header.php';
$template->set_filenames(array(
        'body' => 'item.tpl'
        ));
$template->display('body');
include 'footer.php';
unset($_SESSION['browse_id']);
?>
```

Now if I set the variable directly the variable makes it to the template.

```
$template->assign_vars(array(
    'B_XYZ' => '1',
    ));
```

When I set the template variable equal to another variable the value does not make it to the template.

The variable $xyz is being set within If /ElseIf /Else blocks depending on the condition.  Then the template variables assignment occurs before the foreach loop starts again.

Any ideas?

Don't know if this will help shed context.

```
<!-- IF B_HASGALELRY -->
    <div class="tableContent2">
        <div class="titTable4">
            <a name="gallery"></a>{L_663}
        </div>
        <div class="table2" style="text-align:center; overflow-y:auto;" id="gallery">
        <table>
            <tr>
        <!-- BEGIN gallery -->
                <td>
                    <a href="http://domain.tld/{UPLOADEDPATH}{ID}/{gallery.V}" title=""><!--{SITEURL}-->
            {B_XYZ}
            <!-- IF B_XYZ -->
                    <img src="{SITEURL}{UPLOADEDPATH}{gallery.VPREMADE}" title="" border="0" height=80 hspace="10" >
            <!-- ELSE -->               
                    <img src="http://domain.tld/p.php?w={THUMBWIDTH}&fromfile={UPLOADEDPATH}{ID}/{gallery.V}&auctionid={ID}&fromfileonly={gallery.V}" border="0" width="{THUMBWIDTH}" hspace="10">
            <!-- ENDIF -->
                    </a>
                    /{B_HASGALELRY}
                </td>
        <!-- END gallery -->
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is a scope problem... loosing its value because somehow `'B_XYZ' => '1'` is not the same evaluated here `<!-- IF B_XYZ -->`

Comment: Note that your working code and your non-working code are doing slightly different things. You're assigning the string `'1'` in your manual, direct assignment, and the integer `1` in your problem code. It's hard to know what's going wrong without knowing the template engine or seeing the real code, though.

Comment: (Which template engine are you using? It is possible that its `assign_vars` method simply overwrites all existing template variables?)

Comment: WeBid uses a Template Engine called "WeTPLeng" to parse Theme Files and includes PHP coded file data into the parse file resulting in necessary interaction with a user and outputs the required data to the users monitor. WeTPLeng is based on the popular phpBB Template Engine but, has been customized to work with the WeBid Auction Script. WeBid themes prior to being parsed by the Template Engine are not WC3 100% sytax compliant.

Comment: When I force the array to set B_XYZ => true, /  B_XYZ => 1, / B_XYZ => '1', The template variable B_XYZ is set when the template builds the page. All my other variables in the page set and stay set.

Comment: Template was being redeclared with array_vars late in the file.  By the time the web page was generated per the template the variable declaration had been wiped out by the previous array_vars declaration. Added element to existing loop specific array_block_vars declaration, used in IF